# The chance of infinite tries seems to be too high

Tags: probability

We have an even with five outcomes. Three are irrelevant, each has 1/4 chance. The fourth is failure with 1/8 chance and the fifth is win with 1/8 chance.

The chance of win on first try is $\frac{1}{8}$.

The chance of win on second try is $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{8}$.

So then the chance of winning on first or second try is $(1 + \frac{3}{4}) \times \frac{1}{8}$.

That's infinite geometric series so the chances of winning over infinite tries is $4 \times \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$.

That seems way too high. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Is the calculation correct? I think I must've made a mistake because getting 50% odds in this case just feels too high.

Comment: Why is this too high? Eventually you'll get a meaningful result and it will either be Win or Lose with an equal chance of either.

Comment: At each step you actually have an equal probability of losing or winning since both those outcomes have probability $\frac18$ so this does actually make sense

Comment: The probability $1/2$ is correct. You could see this as a Markov chain with three states, two of which are absorbing and the third one being transient. As others mention, the symmetry of the problem means that the probabilities of being absorbed in the two absorbing states are $1/2$ each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, the result of $(1/2)$ makes perfect sense.

From the problem constraints, you can ignore the first three outcomes, and you are in effect asking: which will occur first, the fourth outcome or the fifth outcome?

An intuitive illustration is:

Imagine a roulette table that has both $0$ and $00$, as well as the other numbers, $1,2,\cdots,36~$ (i.e. $38$ different outcomes).

If you ignore all of the other numbers, besides $0$ and $00$, what is the probability of having the roulette wheel show $0$ before showing $00$?